# How to pop up textbox to input like messagebox?

Tags: input, combobox, popup, messagebox

Hello i use c# and want to put some new value inside of combobox so searching for **How to pop up textbox or any other input control to put value inside of them, that will be send to combobox?**

Basically i want to create input for combobox, that will pop up like messagebox, and just to get some input value.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this in Javascript instead using a prompt box.